# How to decombine and recombine arrays to accelerate processes

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, append, extend

I currently have to multiplicate two arrays A and B, both which are 512*256*256.
By that I understand : shape(A or B) = (512,256,256)

Because I want to multi process it, I need to cut it into pieces to get things done faster.

My idea is this : I want to make a A1 which would be (0:256,0:128,0:128) and a A2 (257:,129:,129:) , same for B.

Make the calculations that way : C1 = A1*B1 ; C2 = A2*B2
And then recombine C1(256,128,128) + C2(256,128,128) = C(512,256,256).

Does this make sense ? By that I mean in a matricial/array way of thinking it ( I am a beginner in that field ). Currently I just do C = A * B and I am fine with that, for smaller arrays.

If so, how can I make work ? Especially for recombining. Append ? Extend ?

Thank you !

Comment: Are familiar with numpy? It makes multiplying arrays trivial. http://www.numpy.org/

Comment: Hi
My problem comes by the fact that  my arrays are too big for the multi processing package available that I use. 
So yes I know how to multiply them, I do it for small arrays, but I need to learn how to cut them and restack them properly to avoid the "to big arrays" issue.

Comment: you mean somethling like the strassen algo? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm

Comment: This is quite interesting. But I am doing my thing because of the Ram consumption lets say.Afterall, what I am looking for is the command to stack an array to another like I described in my message. Step 1 : I cut into half ( OK ) ; Step 2 : I multiply ( seems OK ) ; Step 3 : I restack ( this is what I really do not know )

Comment: I think it might goes witht he "d/h/vstack command" or "concatenate"

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, probably not the best, but still.

First, get your 2 pieces of the too big array.
Than pad the first one with whatever you want, on a lenght equal to the shape of the pieces.
Then copy the data of the second piece to the first piece, replacing the padded values by the good values.